# Insert date into MongoDB with ColdFusion

Tags: java, mongodb, coldfusion

I have problem with inserting a JSONDate correctly into MongoDB. I am using ColdFusion 11, MongoDB 3.01 and the Mongo-Java Driver.

The dates are inserted as strings into the database.

```
<cfset utilDate = CreateObject("java","java.util.Date") />
<cfset utilJSON = CreateObject("java", "com.mongodb.util.JSON") />
<cfset SimpleDaxteFormat  = CreateObject("java", "java.text.SimpleDateFormat").init("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'") />
<cfset SimpleDateFormat2 = CreateObject("java", "java.text.SimpleDateFormat").init("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'+01:00'") />
<cfset jodaIso = CreateObject("java", "org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat") />

<cfset isoDate1 = "2015-03-25T15:23:57.000Z" />
<cfset isoDate2 = "2015-03-25T15:23:57.000+01:00" />
<cfset isoDate3 = "2015-03-25T15:23:57+01:00" />

<!--- Joda Date-Time --->
<cfset jMillis = jodaIso.dateTimeNoMillis() />
<cfset jpdt = jMillis.parseDateTime(isoDate3) />
<cfset jToDateIso = jpdt.toDateTimeISO() />

<!--- Document --->
<cfset doc = {
   "date1" = SimpleDateFormat.parse(isoDate1),
   "date2" = SimpleDateFormat2.parse(isoDate2),
   "date3" = jToDateIso.toDate()
} />

<!--- JSON parsing --->    
<cfset doc = utilJSON.parse(SerializeJSON(doc)) />
<cfset col.save(doc) />
```

Display of the MongoDB collection, the insert is successful but the dates are formatted as strings:

```
> db.datetest.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5512c4fd1e106620a5b49dac"),
    "date1" : "März, 25 2015 15:23:57",
    "date2" : "März, 25 2015 15:23:57",
    "date3" : "März, 25 2015 15:23:57"
}
```

How can I insert the dates as `Date`s, rather than strings?

Comment: What is the datatype of the field in the mongo db?

Comment: All date* fields are Strings (type:2)
db.datetest.find({ date1: { $type: 2 } }) => result==true

Comment: I cannot define a collection field with a specific "type" (Date, String ...).
The data type is determined by the driver as I understand it.
Because MongoDB creates a collection implicitly when the collection is first referenced in a command, ... [Link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/)